# Is there a way to change font size of specific text insde the html table

Tags: html, font-size

My goal is to increase the text size of first 2 [a] tags

```
   <table width="750" class="normal">
    <tr>
    <td height="35" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>
      <strong>Click one of the following PDF's for more information:</strong><br>
      <br>
      <font size="+4px"> <a  href="http://www.gpiparts.com/Rubber_Blankets/Rubber_Blankets-Order_Form.pdf" target="_blank"><strong>Online Order Form</strong></font></a> | 
      <font size="+4px">  <a href="http://www.gpiparts.com/Rubber_Blankets/Rubber_Blankets_Brochure_and_Order_Form.pdf" target="_blank">Literature / Order Form </font></a> |
      <a href="http://www.gpiparts.com/Rubber_Blankets/Replacement_Rubber_Blanket_Install.pdf" target="_blank"><br>Installation / Repair Instructions</a>
```

So far I tried to increase font size in HTML but no success because html does not seems to have CSS attached to it and this html code is coded in the body of phpmyadmin table.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The [`<font>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is deprecated. Use the [`style` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) with inline CSS if you can't add or modify a stylesheet.

Comment: @Sean Warning one he is using obsolete technology that is no longer in the HTML specification is hardly conversational or unproductive.

Comment: @Rob that’s what deprecated means.

Comment: @Sean No it does not. Deprecated means the element is up for removal. Obsolete means the element has been removed. More detailed definition [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/conform.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
<a style="font-size: 40px;"....
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers usually include some explanation along with code.